# how to add caption and span to table

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, jquery-selectors, prepend

Here is existing HTML , yes the developer used nested tables and i cant change the existing HTML , but i need to replace the table class , then add a caption and span to the main table only.

```
<table class="two_column_layout" align="center">
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="two_column_layout" valign="top">
            <table class="report" align="center" cellspacing="1"></table>
        </td>
        <td class="two_column_layout" valign="top">
            <table class="report" align="center" cellspacing="1"></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="two_column_layout" valign="top">
            <table class="report" align="center" cellspacing="1"></table>
        </td>
        <td class="two_column_layout" valign="top">
            <table class="report" align="center" cellspacing="1"></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

I need the new html to look like this

```
<table class="report" align="center">
<caption>
    <span>
        Weekly Results
    </span>
</caption>
<tbody>
    <tr>
        <td class="two_column_layout" valign="top">
            <table class="report" align="center" cellspacing="1"></table>
        </td>
        <td class="two_column_layout" valign="top">
            <table class="report" align="center" cellspacing="1"></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td class="two_column_layout" valign="top">
            <table class="report" align="center" cellspacing="1"></table>
        </td>
        <td class="two_column_layout" valign="top">
            <table class="report" align="center" cellspacing="1"></table>
        </td>
    </tr>
</tbody>
```

So i already changed the table class from "two_column_layout" to "report" by adding this

```
$('#body_options_22 table').removeClass('two_column_layout').addClass('report');
```

but i don't know how to add the caption and span just for the first table.report

```
<caption>
    <span>
        Weekly Results
    </span>
</caption>
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The result is simple. If you need clarifications, do post in the comments.

Add this after your line of JS in your question:

```
$('table.report').first().prepend('<caption><span>Weekly Results</span></caption>');
```

Comment: For screen readers (accessibility), due to bugs in the chrome and firefox implementation, the <caption> should describe what the table is, which is fine here, but there also needs to be a table header row: <tr><th></th><th></th><tr>. The screen readers won't correctly read the <caption> without the <th> row. They should but don't. You should also add <table tabindex="0"> ("1", whatever) so the users can tab through the tables and just read the captions, to find the table they want. If you don't want table headers set the font-size:0px and height:0px on the th tags. thx for script!!!

Answer (score 0):

I think you just want to add a caption to the table??
Then use this.

```
$("table").prepend("<caption><span>Weekly Results</span></caption>");
```